# What is an International Version for Samsung devices?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-j7

I'm trying to buy a Samsung Galaxy J7 and I'm between two options.

- one is: Samsung Galaxy J5 SM-J500H/DS GSM Factory Unlocked Smartphone, International Version
- other is : Samsung Galaxy J7 SM-J700H/DS GSM Factory Unlocked Smartphone-Android 5.1, 5.5-Inch

I would like to know the differences between both of them (if there is any). Also, I want to know whether the phone is able to function well or not in my country, Ecuador South America.

Comment: Did you not notice that the first one is a J5, not a J7?

Comment: Also, be aware that the H-suffixed variants are 3G-only. The F/FD-suffixed variants are also deemed "international" and support LTE.

Answer (score 0):

This is two different models.
Look here about:
[J5 VS J7](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/samsung-galaxy-j7-2720-vs-samsung-galaxy-j5-2719)